# Handlebars.js compile prepending and appending "//" to output

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

Appreciate the help on this one. Frustrating that I can't figure this one out. Take a look at the screenshot below. See those beginning and trailing slashes that sandwich the content? Can't figure out why those are included in the output. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Here's the js:

```
var source = $j("#src").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source, preventIndent);
var output = template(data);       
$j("#data-wrapper").html(output);
```

Here's the html:

```
<div id="data-wrapper"></div>
<script id="src" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Number</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {{#each this}}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{number}}</td> 
                </tr>
             {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</script>
```

and here's what I get:

```
<div id="data-wrapper" style="min-height: 500px; position: relative;">//  

    <table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Number</td>
                <td>Short Description</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>ENHC0010005</td> 
                    <td>Enable module relationships to the Enhancement and Defect forms.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>ENHC0010010</td> 
                    <td>This is a short description which will display as the body text of a slack message...hopefully.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>ENHC0010014</td> 
                    <td>This is a short description which will display as the body text of a slack message...hopefully.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>ENHC0010015</td> 
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>ENHC0010017</td> 
                    <td>This is the short description</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>ENHC0010018</td> 
                    <td>Short description here</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>ENHC0010020</td> 
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>ENHC0010021</td> 
                    <td>Another test of new channel name</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>ENHC0010026</td> 
                    <td>Application Access fulfillment request</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>ENHC0010029</td> 
                    <td>Application Access fulfillment request</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
//</div>
```

And the data structure:

[image]

Comment: Can you include the inputs, and the actual HTML that is rendered.

Comment: @TankorSmash edited my post to include the rendered html. When you say inputs, are you referring to the data?

Comment: Where does position-relative come from

Comment: @TankorSmash it comes from a bit of js I include for a spinner before output is displayed. That's actually something I added AFTER already having this // issue.

Comment: can you cut down your code until only the slashes show up?

Comment: @TankorSmash good call. i'll do that and that should provide some clues. Thanks!